# How to reload the page without losing variables value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, struts2

I have in simulation.jsp the following code, by which I receive some simulation data from struts2 action:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var data='<s:property escape="false" value="simInfos" />';
}
```

Now I do some simulation with this data. After the simulation has been done, how can I reload/refresh this page with button-click without losing this data, which I have received from struts2 action?

Comment: If it's a lot of data you need to use ajax to store and retrieve it from the server.

Comment: use hiddenfield control to store variable value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data='<s:property escape="false" value="simInfos" />';
    localStorage["myData"] = data;

    // later on (maybe after page refresh, whatever)
    var myLoadedData = localStorage["myData"];
}
```

You can treat HTML5's [localStorage](http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-one/) like any other object, although it has specific setter and getter functions and can only store strings. Don't treat it like a permanent cache though, just a place to store some data for a little while. [Another reference](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Comment: @ Elliot Bonneville: Thanks, that was helpfull :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use this Cross-browser local storage API: http://www.jstorage.info/

You can use it like how you use HTM5's localStorage ;D

```
$.jStorage.set("foo", "value");  //Set "value" in "foo"
var txt = $.jStorage.get("foo");  //"txt" is now "value"
```